# Colorbox: Width and height from URI

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have another colorbox specific question (http://wakawaka.reh-kendermann.df-kunde.de/media/media)

When I load the media page via ajax i have to reinitialise colorbox.
this is working (it´s the vimeo-vid):

```
$("#content-page a.colorbox-load").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:580, innerHeight:326});
```

The link looks like:

```
<a href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/26436619?height=326&width=580&iframe=true&show_title=0&show_byline=0&show_portrait=0&autoplay=1" class="colorbox-load"><img width="250" src="http://109.239.49.88:12001/files/uploads/project_data_files_2/waka_video.jpg"></a>
```

but when I only use

```
$("#content-page a.colorbox-load").colorbox({iframe:true});
```

it´s not working. shouldn´t colorbox use width and height from the link?

Greetings Lars

Comment: The link has width but not height just have a look.

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't take those values from the URL.  Maybe you are thinking of Thickbox, which uses URL parameters.

Comment: Thankyou, i´m gonna take the vars from the uri via JQuery.